# Display webform results

Tags: 7, views, hooks, webforms

I want to display webform submitted data in a view. How to recover submissions of my webform in a list?

I think that I can use hook_views_query_alter to change my view's query.

If that's right, how can I implement it?

Any idea please? Thank you!

Comment: There are couple of default disabled views `SITENAME/admin/structure/views`  and If you don't meet your requirement in the default views then provide more explanations

Comment: In the database, all submissions of the webform are linked to a single node. So when I create for example a **projec**t content type and activate the webform above, it only returns a single submission. While I'm trying to display all the submissions in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to **add new view**  '**admin/structure/views/add**' and into Show select **webform submission** continue and edit ... you can get all the submission list into the view.

[image]

Add field webform submission data:value [image]

Then select webform node and field you want.
[image]

You can see the fields like this
[image]

View result 
[image]

So, you can get all fields which you created when you create a web form.

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I tested that but it returns **Serial numbers**. I need to display all data related to submissions

Comment: Then only set   **FORMAT** as **Table** and add **FIELDS**   


Webform submissions: Serial number (Serial number),
Webform submissions: Completed (Completed),
Webform submissions: Sid (Sid),
Webform submissions: Submitted (Submitted),
Webform submissions: User (User),
Webform submissions: View link.

Comment: You can see the above screenshot as I added new.

Comment: Thanks Sir, that's cool but it's not what I am looking to display.. I want to display all data related to submissions => my webform contains many fields (address, phone, country, name...) I want to display this!

Comment: Thnks to ask in detail, I updated my answer you can see and follow after you can get all the submission data. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks Sir, your answer is very clear.. But in my **Configure field: Webform submission data: All values** I don't have the webform node and component data options!! And yet I will mark your answer as a solution. Maybe I miss a module.. I am grateful

Comment: I chosen **Configure field: Webform submission data: All values** I have to choose **Configure field: Webform submission data: Value** It's resolved :) Many thanks

Comment: Hi Sir, can I add a new **Data type** in my **Configure field: Webform submission data: Value** ? Thank you

Comment: Yes as created your webform to add new field with new data type and after submit you will add it.

Comment: Thank you. in my view I added a (multiple_file) field which returns some thing like <a href="../image1.png">image1.png</a>  <a href="../image2.jpg">image2.jpg</a> I want to change that to <img src="../image1.png" /> (just the first image and as a thumbnail). Is there a drupal trick to do that? Thank you

Comment: Sorry your answer is not clear, But if you just want to add images on view then add new field in your web form as image field type and then as follow previews field select by  Configure field: Webform submission data: Value.

Comment: Not exactly but thanks anyway :)

Comment: field: "Webform submission data: Value" is not appearing? What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Yuu can use https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views to display submission.

For More info you can visit : https://knackforge.com/blog/sivaji/displaying-webform-submission-data-drupal-views

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work with me! I am using drupal 7.56